# Is p53 a cyclin dependent kinase?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cancer, medicine, cell-cycle

I've been reading some research papers about p53 and associated tumour suppressor proteins, such as p21. I see them referred to and associated with cyclin-dependent kinases. Is p53,p63 et cetera part of the CDK family?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you might still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). To start there is an extensive [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P53) that contains links to many other resources. ——— Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also take the time to go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: p53 is not even a kinase forget cyclin dependent kinase.

Answer (score 6):

No, p53 and other tumor suppressor proteins do not belong to Cyclin dependent kinase(CDK)family. p53 blocks the cell cycle by promoting the synthesis of Cyclin dependent kinase inhibitors (CKI proteins). These CKI proteins bind with the Cyclin and CDK complex and inhibit the cell cycle at G1 checkpoint.

[image]

(Image Source:  https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/cellular-molecular-biology/stem-cells-and-cancer/a/cell-cycle-regulators)

p53 also plays role in activating DNA repair enzymes and if DNA is not repaired, p53 will promote apoptosis, so that defective DNA is not passed on.

These all proteins are structurally homologous to p53, so together they are known as p53 family.

(Via: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fonc.2014.00285/full)

Comment: This is a nice answer, but please don't answer [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) style questions — this is something the OP could (and should) have looked up for themselves!

Comment: ok..I’ll keep that in mind for future

Comment: Fluffy question, good answer :)